# Is it possible to forward physical path in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

Is there a way in a simple asp.net application to make

a subpath of `/` located in `c:/app` 
Map a virtual path `/app/areas/1` map to `D:/areas/1`

Without telling iis at an application level(ie configuring iis)?

Either a programmatic/mvc or web.config solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a virtual directory:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory

But if for some reason you're prevented from doing so, you can look at creating a VirtualPathProvider, although that might be overkill:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441